# VHDL: how do I perform multiple things for one case?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am getting this error message which i don't understand for this codepiece

```
Segmentvalue: process(Anode,counter_1r, counter_10r,counter_100r, counter_1000r)
begin
case anode is 
when  0 => An <= "1110" && segment <= counter_1r;
when    1 => AN <= "1101" && segment <= counter_10r;
when    2 => An <= "1011" && segment <= counter_100r;
When  3 => An <= "0111" && segment <= counter_1000r;
when others => null;
end case;

end process;
```

It's likely because of the use of && which usually used in c++ when multiple things have to be done, but how is it vhdl?

Comment: `&&` is the AND conditional operator in c++ (and just about every other language) and so is not used for multiple statements anyway. The   statements are just semi-colon(;) separated as I suspect they should be in VHDL as well.

Comment: Also note 1 of your `An` is `AN` which is probably a typo. Make sure it doesn't exist in your real code also.

Comment: VHDL is case insensitive @TristanBurnside. It doesn't look nice, but it would work.

Comment: cool, @Philippe thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Segmentvalue: process(Anode,counter_1r, counter_10r,counter_100r, counter_1000r)
begin
case anode is 
when  0 => An <= "1110"; segment <= counter_1r;
when    1 => AN <= "1101"; segment <= counter_10r;
when    2 => An <= "1011"; segment <= counter_100r;
When  3 => An <= "0111"; segment <= counter_1000r;
when others => null;
end case;

end process;
```

Comment: just remember that VHDL is case ensitive, and An is not the same as AN

Comment: wikipedia says that it is not http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL#Design but I would say that it is better style to be consistant